# Uploading then Serving Images on a Load Balanced Amazon AWS Setup

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-web-services

I am setting up a load balanced system on Amazon AWS. I will be uploading photos to my server and then reading the photos off the server from another device.

Let's say I have `Server-A` and `Server-B` running on my load balancer. If I upload a photo and hit `Server-A`, then I am assuming I won't be able to see the photo on `Server-B`.

What is the best way to handle this? Should I create `Server-C` to hold the photos and access `Server-C` from whichever server I hit with the load balancer? Then there is no load balancing on `Server-C`, so I would have to setup a backup server that copies the files from `Server-C` every X minutes?

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a distributed filesystem like GlusterFS or NFS with DRBD running on server C and D (redundancy) to share the data directories with photos to Server A and B.

Instead, as jamieb suggested, its much much simpler if you upload it to S3 and retrieve from there. It will be cheaper (~$0.13/GB) than running 2 instances in HA mode and 99.99999% available.

There are SDK's for many languages to talk to S3 -- http://aws.amazon.com/code/

You can use tools like s3cmd and many more to talk to s3 for file upload and download

Answer (score 0):

No, instance states have to be consistent (need to be identical) to properly work behind a load-balancer.  The proper solution to this problem is to upload your photos directly to S3.

Comment: Or a clustered filesystem like Gluster.